# Can logging be enabled in FirewallD

Tags: fedora, logs, firewalld

I'm running Fedora 20 and would like to see what my firewall is doing in the background. Is it possible to view a log of the traffic blocked by FirewallD?

Comment: [Configuring Logging for Denied Packets](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_logging_for_denied_packets)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/firewalld-users/2013-February/000049.html), the FirewallD logs are at `/var/log/firewalld`. To get debug messages, you need to run it with `--debug` or `--debug=2`.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is a dated post, but I've been searching for this today, and have found tons of old blogs that attempt to address this issue.  For the public, this update from Red Hat should be more available than only to subscribers:

Upgrade to firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.el7 from Errata RHSA-2016:2597

Specify which packets should be logged

```
firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=<value>
```

value may be one of: all, unicast, broadcast, multicast, or off

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1191593

Comment: this can also be set manually in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl -x -f | grep 'DROP\|REJECT'` afterwards to inspect denied packets.

Answer (score 7):

You need append the line in `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld`
for maximum details:

```
FIREWALLD_ARGS=--debug=10
```

Then restart `firewalld` service

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

It's better, than edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service`.

Answer (score 6):

For logging the traffic blocked by `firewalld`, the following approach with `rsyslogd` worked for me:

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld` and update the value for `LogDenied` to `all` (or as required)

```
LogDenied=all
```

restart firewalld

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

This typically adds logging rules just before reject/drop rules in the firewall, something like:

```
LOG  all  --  anywhere   anywhere  LOG level warning prefix "IN_drop_DROP: "
LOG  all  --  anywhere   anywhere  LOG level warning prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
```

Create a file named `/etc/rsyslog.d/custom_iptables.conf` (note extension is.conf) and add the following statements to it:

```
:msg,contains,"_DROP" /var/log/iptables.log
:msg,contains,"_REJECT" /var/log/iptables.log
& stop
```

restart rsyslog

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Now the dropped and rejected packets will be logged to `/var/log/iptables.log`

Comment: ⁺¹, I confirm seeing rejected entries in `journalctl -f`. FWIW, initially, basing on the other answer, I only did the LogDenied=all part, but it was not enough.

Comment: since nowadays firewalld doesn't use iptables by default, may I recommend to rename `_iptables.conf` → to `_firewalld.conf` to lessen confusion?

Comment: Ok, I'm just redoing this on the other PC using this answer, and I noted one discrepancy worth mentioning: I don't have `/etc/sysconfig` dir, instead I'm editing `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` file. I didn't notice it the last time I used this answer because `LogDenied=all` step I did using the other answer.